# Deploy HPA (Horizontal Pod Autoscaler) based custom metric (http request)?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I am deploying my application using HPA algorithm based on http request. 
I follow this [link](https://dzone.com/articles/ensure-high-availability-and-uptime-with-kubernete).
In the "Auto Scaling Based on Custom Metrics" part. I built successfully with their application. But when I deploy with my application, I get the error:

```
$ kubectl get --raw "/apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/namespaces/default/pods/*/http_requests" | jq .
Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the metric http_requests for pods
```

In this part, they said that "The podinfo app exposes a custom metric named http_requests_total". So, how can my application expose a custom metric like that?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find more information about this deployment [here](https://github.com/stefanprodan/k8s-podinfo).
Another example how to build application for custom metrics you can find [here](https://github.com/vishen/k8s-custom-metrics/) and [here](https://medium.com/@zhimin.wen/custom-prometheus-metrics-for-apps-running-in-kubernetes-498d69ada7aa).
In both cases the are using "**[Golang Client API](https://github.com/prometheus/client_golang)**"

> In the example from your tutorial there is working application on port 9898
>   
>  tcp       0      0 :::9898                 :::*                    LISTEN      1/podinfo

If you are not sure if your application is working properly than please verify:

```
    kubectl get deploy,pods
    -- verify if your new deployment is working properly 
    kubectl describe <your pod>
    -- in case of any issues with your application:
    kubectl logs <your pod>
    -- if the port and an endpoint are the same as in the example
    curl <your pod ip (endpoint)>:9898/metrics 
       you should notice http_requests_total metrics: htp_requests_total{status="200"} 1926 
    -- for generall issues
    kubectl get events
```

Please share with your findings and results.